# How can I catch typescript type errors in a Vue component's data?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I recently started developing in Typescript with Nuxt-ts and Vue 2. I was trying to avoid writing the app with [class-style components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components) so I was using the following solution.

I declare my Interfaces in a folder called `/types`. If I want to declare a `type` in the Vue component's `data`, I import the type and then use it inside the component.

```js
// types/Fruit.ts

export interface Fruit {
  name: string,
  color: string,
  taste: string
}
```

```js
// components/FruitComponent.vue

<script lang="ts">

import Vue from 'vue'
import { Fruit } from '@/types/fruits'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'FruitComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      fruit: {
        name: 'apple',
        color: 'red',
        taste: 'delicious',
        wrongParameter: 'this should be an error',
      } as Fruit
    }
  }
})

</script>
```

The problem is, the compiler and the Visual Code editor won't catch an error such as the one seen above.

I was expecting an error similar to `Object literal wrongParameter is not assignet to type 'Fruit'`.

How should I do this correctly to catch this type of errors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Vue, but I'm absolutely and entirely sure there is no way to do this.

All types exist *only* during compilation, all interfaces, type aliases, function overloads, unions or whatever typescript-related, basically anything that exists in typescript but not in javascript is entirely gone after compilation and cannot be used in whatever way at runtime. This means there is no kind of `try...catch` block that would catch typescript errors. The point of typescript is to provide *compile-time* type checking.

Also there is no error to catch in your code. If you didn't write `as Fruit`, then typescript compiler would consider this code an error and show you a message that your code is potentially wrong. But when you write `as Fruit` you essentially tell the compiler "I know this object is not quite what you expect, but I'm sure its compatible with `Fruit`. Even if it's not compatible, I'm completely sure everything will be fine and no code will break, so just don't check this object and pretend it's a `Fruit` even though it's not". It's now your problem to ensure everything will indeed be fine, if something breaks, typescript cannot help.

Typescript type system is not like Java or C++ or whatever, it doesn't guarantee everything will be fine at runtime, it just prevents you from doing stupid errors that can be avoided just by looking at your code and lets you write code faster by providing type hints in your IDE. If you take a look at typescript goals or, more specifically, [non-goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals), you will see the fifth one

> Non-goal 5: Add or rely on run-time type information in programs, or emit different code based on the results of the type system. Instead, encourage programming patterns that do not require run-time metadata.

This basically means what I've just written above: typescript doesn't guarantee everything will be fine at runtime. Like if you write the following code:

```
interface ApiResponse {
  foo: {
    bar: string
  }
}

fetch('http://myapi.com')
  .then<ApiResponse>(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data.foo.bar))
```

Typescript cannot guarantee that `data` will indeed have property `foo` which has property `bar`, it's your duty to check it. If it turns out that the API sends an empty object, for example, then `res.json()` will return an empty object, consequently `data` will be an empty object and `data.foo.bar` will generate an error because `foo` is undefined and you cannot read property `bar` of undefined. Typescript cannot help you here

Comment: @maikelinhas, yes, this is actually how it's supposed to work. You only write type assertions (`as ...`) when you need the skip type validation for some particular object, this is often useful but usually you want to avoid it. In this case of course this assertion is completely unnecessary

Comment: Thank you very much!! I removed my previous comment since it was a bit messy and included the proposed solution in my question.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue,Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';  
import { Fruit } from '@/types/fruits'
  
@Component({
  name: 'FruitComponent', 
  components: { 
  }
} )
export default class FruitComponent extends Vue { 

@Prop(  {required: true, type : Object} ) fruit1 !: Fruit ;

fruit2 : Fruit  = { name: 'apple',
        color: 'red',
        taste: 'delicious',
        wrongParameter: 'this should be an error'};//this create an error
 
 
  mounted(){}
}
</script>
```